# Pandas convert strings to numeric if possible; else keep string values

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, numeric

I have a Pandas Dataframe which has columns which look something like this:

```
df:

Column0   Column1     Column2
'MSC'       '1'        'R2'
'MIS'       'Tuesday'  '22'
'13'        'Finance'  'Monday'
```

So overall, in these columns are actual strings but also numeric values (integers) which are in string format.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas) nice post about the `pd.to_numeric` and `astype()` methods, but I can't see if or how I could use them in my case.

Using:

```
pd.to_numeric(df, errors = 'ignore')
```

just results in skiping the whole columns. Instead of skipping the whole columns, I only want to skip the strings in those columns which can't be converted, move on to the next entry and try to convert the next string.

So in the end, my dataframe would look like this:

```
df:

Column0   Column1     Column2
'MSC'       1          'R2'
'MIS'      'Tuesday'    22
 13        'Finance'  'Monday'
```

Is there maybe an efficient way to loop over these columns and achieve that?

Best regards,
Jan

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all your suggestions! Since I am still a python beginner, @coldspeed and @sacul 's answers are easier to understand for me so I will go with one of them!

Comment: This just doesn't fit into the pandas model. You're looking for mixed types in a single column... unless you just prefer pandas syntax, you're losing any kind of efficiency gains you might get in data processing

Comment: Do you still need to retain the strings that won't convert? If so, would moving them to a new column be acceptable? Mixed data types in a single column doesn't work.

Comment: @roganjosh, although sometimes when you are using pandas to clean up data that you received with mixed types, this is relevant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

100% agree with the comments—mixing dtypes in columns is a terrible idea, performance wise.

For reference, however, I would do this with `pd.to_numeric` and `fillna`:

```
df2 = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(df)
print(df2)
  Column0  Column1 Column2
0     MSC        1      R2
1     MIS  Tuesday      22
2      13  Finance  Monday
```

Columns are cast to `object` dtype to prevent coercion. You can see this when you extract the `values`:

```
print(df2.values.tolist())
[['MSC', 1.0, 'R2'], ['MIS', 'Tuesday', 22.0], [13.0, 'Finance', 'Monday']]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would apply `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`, and `update` the original dataframe according to the results (see caveats in comments):

```
# show original string type:
df.loc[0,'Column1']
# '1'

df.update(df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'))

>>> df
  Column0  Column1 Column2
0     MSC        1      R2
1     MIS  Tuesday      22
2      13  Finance  Monday

# show updated float type:
df.loc[0,'Column1']
# 1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could simply use the `isnumeric()` method of `str`. I like it because the syntax is clear, although according to coldspeed's comment, this can become very slow on large df.

> `df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x)`

Example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([['a','b','c'],['1','1a','c']],columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0    a    b    c
1    1   1a    c

In [4]: df.Col1.map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x)
Out[4]:
0    a
1    1
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Please add a disclaimer that this can become very slow for large DataFrames.

Answer (score 3):

Using `to_numeric` + `ignore`

```
df=df.applymap(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x,errors='ignore'))
df
  Column0  Column1 Column2
0     MSC        1      R2
1     MIS  Tuesday      22
2      13  Finance  Monday
df.applymap(type)
                 Column0                Column1                Column2
0          <class 'str'>  <class 'numpy.int64'>          <class 'str'>
1          <class 'str'>          <class 'str'>  <class 'numpy.int64'>
2  <class 'numpy.int64'>          <class 'str'>          <class 'str'>
```